# Special criteria for histogram equalization measure

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, histogram-equalization

let us consider following code -which reads image, applies  histogram equalization procedure and display both result :

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
img = cv2.imread('original.png', cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
assert img is not None, "file could not be read, check with os.path.exists()"
equ = cv2.equalizeHist(img)
res = np.hstack((img,equ)) #stacking images side-by-side
cv2.imshow("both image",res)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

result is :
[image]

we can  see clearly that contrast of the image was increased, but as you know almost every  part of the AI  , Machine learning or computer vision  tasks  is evaluated by some criteria, for example in deep learning we have notion of loss function(like a binary_crossentropy, mean_squared_error and etc), so my question is : is there  any  measurment  scale   whch will be suitable  to  the  contrast increasment ?  so if  i would like to ask : by how much or  how large  changement has been  made after histogram equalization, is there any score for this? sure i can calculate difference between two image as they have same dimension and calculate  square of difference(therefore  squared distance between two image) but is it correct? maybe  difference between two  histogram(difference between two distribution) will be right action to be done?if so could you tell me please how?

Comment: equalized histogram will have approximately *flat* histogram (CDF is a diagonal line). -- are you asking for distance measures that are defined on histograms? there's the earth mover's distance. there is the Euclidean distance. there are others...

Comment: so i am looking for distance between two image after changes are done, so which one is  relevant distance?

Comment: that's a conceptual question, not a programming question. asking for literature review to be done is beyond the scope of Stack Overflow and perhaps better suited to another stack exchange site. I am also hesitant to give an opinion on what distance measure you should use. that's for you to decide.

Comment: This question is more suited to https://dsp.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Also, before you post this on the DSP stack exchange, think about what exactly are you asking for: Do you want to quantify how much the image changed? Do you want to measure contrast, so you can say how much the contrast increased? Do you you want to determine how well the task was accomplished (ie how flat the output histogram is)? State this clearly in the question!